# Is there a way in CakePHP to partially re-render a view on the server-side when requesting data asynchronously?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I'm planning on experimenting a bit with the HTML5 History API on my website to asynchronously render new content and save states for the browsers that support it. Obviously this means making a lot of AJAX requests to the server, and I've hit a snag in terms of design approach. I've some areas on the site that already render content asynchronously in small ways, and in those places I've just been rolling my own solutions to generate the new HTML on the client side.

However, what I'm trying to do now will require a bit more of a robust solution, and I'd like to do it in a way that takes advantage of the MVC flow rather than relying on a javascript templating engine or my own whacky javascript to handle the raw data returned by my controllers. Since this feature will only be relevant to certain HTML5 capable browsers, I'd rather not introduce a lot of extra bloat on the client side for something a lot of people may not even see.

Essentially, what I'm wondering is: is there a way in Cake to take advantage of the presentation logic that's already in my view files to selectively generate and return just the new, ready-to-go HTML that I need instead of reinventing the wheel to do it on the client side from raw data returned by the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your problem but i sounds like you want to cache the view which is in fact rendered by a view class but send back to the browser through the controller by using the CakeResponse object.

- Caching: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html
- Response: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

Comment: Basically I want to be able to only partially render a view on an AJAX request to be returned as a string of HTML. For instance, if a user clicks a link for another post, I'd like to use the view file I've already written to render the HTML for JUST the content of the post, and return that without having it build all the HTML of the view and the layout in their entirety. I believe I may have found a solution in `$this->render('/elements/some_element')`